# chart.GetHtmlImageMap not working as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, charts

Gents,

I need help to create an imagemap to my web app's charts. After reading many resources, here and on the web, I end up with the following problem:

The Problem:
   On my view I' am calling @Html.Action(RenderMyMap), that renders an <map> tag, with an atribute coords=0,0,0,0.

What Am I doing:
My project is organized this way:

-Core.cs: Class responsable to create the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart objects;
   -ClientController: With an existing Chart object, I'm saving it with Chat.SaveImage(memoryStream,format), storing it in a session variable as a byte array, and returning a ContentResult object, like in return Content(chart.GetHtmlImageMap());
   -ClientController: After that, I'am using the session variable to actually render the chart, like in return File(chartByteArray,"image/png");
   -Index.cshtml: Finally in my view I'am calling method on the ClientController to render the map and the chart.

My setup:
.NET 4.0, MVC3, SQL Server 2008.

Bellw goes the code of one of my methods, on the ClientController, to generate and return n ImageMap.

```
    public ActionResult ChartMapGetClientsByType()
    {
        System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart = null;
        if (Session["GraficoClientePorTipo"] != null)
        {
            chart = (System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart)Session["GraficoClientePorTipo"];
            Session.Remove("GraficoClientePorTipo");
        }
        else
        {
            chart = MeuMRP.Core.Chart.CreateChartImageMap("GraficoClientePorTipo", SeriesChartType.Pie);
            chart.IsMapEnabled = true;
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            chart.SaveImage(ms, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            Session["GraficoClientePorTipo"] = ms.ToArray();
        }
        return Content(chart.GetHtmlImageMap("GraficoClientePorTipo"));
    }
```

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `Url` property to the `Chart.Series` object. For example:

```
chart.Series[0].Url = "#";
```

Answer (score 0):

This error resulted for me on a complex chart with a set of BoxPlots. 
For a simple **Points** chart, there was no error, the `<map>` was fine with coordinates and attributes.

In order for the map area coordinates to be generated, you need to add a ToolTip or a URL or MapAreaAttributes: e.g.

`series.Points[idx].ToolTip = tooltip;`

or

```
series.Points[idx].MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=\"DisplayTooltip('" + tooltip +"');\" onmouseout=\"DisplayTooltip('');\"";
```

But I found the ***ToolTip*** to be ***useless*** because it added nothing to the `<area>` in the `<map>` except for the coordinates (what am I doing wrong?). I did not test assigning a Url,  assuming that works as asserted in another answer.

Adding the mouseover and mouseout  ***MapAreaAttributes*** works just fine resulting in this:

```
<area onmouseover="DisplayTooltip('99');" onmouseout="DisplayTooltip('');" shape="rect" coords="98,44,103,49" alt="">
```

FYI You can find more details on setting up Web.UI Charting in MVC, at various URI, including 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297677/Using-ASP-Net-Charting-with-Image-Map-in-MVC
http://geekswithblogs.net/DougLampe/archive/2011/01/23/charts-in-asp.net-mvc-2-with-drill-down.aspx.